# Export Variable contents to file

Tags: powershell, variables

I have contents in a variable from GitHub and I want to export then to file automatically created o my local machine

I have tried to use

```
$FileContent | Out-File ('C:\Devjobs\clonefolder' + '\' + $repo.name + '\' + $srccontent.name)
```

It gives the error

```
Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Devjobs\clonefolder\bct-common-devcomm-codegen-messages\BCT.Common.DevComm.CodeGen.Messages.sln'.
At line:1 char:18
+ ... lnContent | Out-File ('C:\Devjobs\clonefolder' + '\' + $repo.name + ' ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Comment: Your given path does not seem to exist already.

Comment: You can specify `-Force` to have it *force* create the file and write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stackprotector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614225/export-variable-contents-to-file#comment124828865_70614225) already commented, the error shows `DirectoryNotFoundException`, which means you are trying to create a file in a directory that does not yet exist.

To avoid that, first create the path for the output file, then create the file.

```
$pathOut = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Devjobs\clonefolder' -ChildPath $repo.name
# create the folder path if it does not exist already
$null = New-Item -Path $pathOut -ItemType Directory -Force
# now write the file
$FileContent | Set-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $pathOut -ChildPath $srccontent.name)
```

By using the `-Force` switch on `New-Item` you will either create the directory, OR have a DirectoryInfo object returned if the folder already existed.
In this case, we have no further need for that object, so we discard it with `$null =`.

Beware that this only works like that **on the file system**, if you would do the same on a registry key, you wil lose all content of the existing key!

Note: I use `Set-Content` rather than `Out-File` because on PowerShell versions up to and including 5.1, `Out-File` without using the `-Encoding` parameter will write the file in **Unicode** (UTF16-LE) encoding which may or may not be what you expect.

---

Following your comment:

```
foreach ($srccontent in $srccontents) {  
    if (<cond>) {  
        $slnContent = <rest>  
        $NewslnContent = "content"  
        $pathOut = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Devjobs\clonefolder' -ChildPath $repo.name  
        # first create the folder path if it does not exist already
        $null = New-Item -Path $pathOut -ItemType Directory -Force  
        # now write the file
        $NewslnContent | Set-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $pathOut -ChildPath $srccontent.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works for me. however running it in iteration, it does not create all the folders for each repo as needed.

Comment: @CalebAdepoju Can you elaborate on _all the folders for each repo_? Should the code create several subfolders too? Could it be sometimes `$repo.name` is empty?

Comment: Remove line `$NewslnContent | Out-File ('C:\Devjobs\clonefolder' + '\' + $repo.name + '\' + $srccontent.name) -Force`. Please see my edit. A file can only be written in a folderpath if that path is created first.

Comment: Thanks alot. it works as expected and I have the files I need in the subfolders accordingly.

Comment: I would like to download subfolders in each repo and have them stay in the same folders as the files i have exported.

Comment: @CalebAdepoju Please explain what you mean by _download subfolders in each repo_. Where do they come from? BTW.. this really sounds like you need to post a new question for that as the original question here is answered.

Comment: sorry @Theo

I would like to download subfolders in each repo and have them stay in the same folders as the files i have exported. 

Let's say i want to get a folder "src" from each repo and all their contents which will include dir and files. so all these dir/files should be downloaded to the same folder. C:\Devjobs\clonefolder\$repo.name

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string concatenation you may want to try `Join-Path` for cross-platform. That being said, if you are on a Windows machine this is not likely to be your issue.

You may want to use `Test-Path` to verify if the path and the file exists already.

```
$path = 'C:' |
    Join-Path -ChildPath 'Devjobs' |
    Join-Path -ChildPath 'clonefolder' |
    Join-Path -ChildPath $repo.name
$filepath = $path | Join-Path -ChildPath $srccontent.name

If (-Not (Test-Path $path)) {
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $path
}
If (-Not (Test-Path $filepath)) {
    Remove-Item -Path $filepath
}

$FileContent | Out-File $filepath
```